# Entity Framework 3.5SP1 insert in wrong order

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Quoted from Alex James' answer [Row insertion order entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921442/row-insertion-order-entity-framework):

> The order that you do things on the context can be in conflict with these rules. For example if you do this:
>   ctx.AddToProducts(   new Product{      Name = "Bovril",      Category = new Category {Name = "Food"}   });
>
> but because of referential integrity constraints we must re-order like this before attempting to insert into the database:
>   Category
>   Product

My problem is that my code suddenly inserts items in the wrong order, namely:

> Product
>   Category

which is very wrong.
Could everyone tell me where I need to look at to troubleshoot this issue? I'm sure that my Category table doesn't have any FK to any other tables.

### Thank you :-)

Edit: extensive trial and error every revision showed me that it is because Association data in edmx file was accidentally removed!
Thanks everyone for helping me :-)

Comment: " my code suddenly inserts items in the wrong order" - do you mean it works sometimes?

Comment: Yes - it used to work. We have tried to track all the code changes but had no luck so far. None of the changes is suspicious to me :-S So I come here to look for a clue :-)

Comment: is it possible that the underlying database changed?

Comment: @Alex: yes, it might be. The database has changed a little bit, but all involved tables are the same. I don't know what could cause this

Comment: maybe the FK constrain dropped?

Comment: This suddenly started happening to me today after updating the model from database. Thanks to your hint I checked the association data and spared a lot of time troubleshooting the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Maybe there's something wrong with the universe, but probably not](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/25/maybe-there-s-something-wrong-with-the-universe-but-probably-not.aspx). Since it used to work, the problem is clearly in your code.

Thus start by eliminating all factors. E.g. write a small test that inserts a category and a product, save that. Work from there: if it fails, monitor the generated SQL, double-check the database schema, verify the entity framework model (store model, mapping, object model).

If the first test succeeds, look where the differences are with your actual code. Add code until it starts failing again.

Work systematically, eventually you will find the error.

Comment: been there, done that. A very simple unittest failed as well. The first executed query was the insertion of Product, which failed

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert into Customer_Receipt_Table
(
    MemAsso_Code,MAName,Allotmentno,Name,SchemeName,
    InstallmentAmount,InstallmentNo,ModeOfPay,
    CU_Date,VaucharNo,Date
) 
values
(
     '" + lblintroducerid.Text + "',
     '" + lblmaname.Text + "',
     '" + lblallotmentno.Text + "',
     '" + lblname.Text + "',
     '" + lblScheme.Text + "',
     '" + lblinsamnt.Text + "',
     '1',
     '" + radiobtnpayment.SelectedItem.Text + "',
     '" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "',
     '" + txtvousherno.Text + "',
     '" + lbldate.Text + "'
);
```