# Maintaining the insert order with Breeze

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js, breeze

**EDIT for people that stumble upon this question in the future.**

This is not a breeze issue, it is an EF issue and has been asked many times on SO. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921442/row-insertion-order-entity-framework) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521057/insertion-order-of-multiple-records-in-entity-framework).

I am using Breeze with Knockout. I am creating entities and pushing them to an array and when saving the changes to the server the data ends up in a different order than how it was pushed on the client. I am using Web API and Entity Framework.

The Javascript code looks like this:

```
var owner = manager.createEntity('OwnerInformation');
licApp().owners.push(owner);
```

Before `SaveChanges` is called the array looks like this:

[image]

When `SaveChanges` is called the `saveBundle` looks like this (ommiting a lot of other info for brevity)

```
{"entities": [
  {
    "Id": 2008,

  {
    "Id": -3,
    "LicensingApplicationId": 2008,
    "FirstName": "First",
    "LastName": "Owner",
  },
  {
    "Id": -4,
    "LicensingApplicationId": 2008,
    "FirstName": "Second",
    "LastName": "Owner",
  }
]}
```

but after saving to the database the result is this (the first column is the id):

[image]

Why are they being inserted backwards?

Comment: I had a similar problem before and I haven't seen it since - I thought, and may be wrong, that it had to do with the way I was setting the navigation property (sounds crazy) but have you tried owner().licApp(licApp()) instead of adding the owner to the licApp?

Comment: @PWKad still the same result!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a higher order question for you. Why do you care? You're using a relational database. Order is not defined. If you care about order, your data should have something to orderBy.

I'm not trying to be snarky. I honestly believe that the expectation of save order sets you up for failure. Convince me otherwise. I'm ready to learn.

p.s.: I don't think Breeze has anything to do with it ... on client or server. I'll bet you're using EF. I've never been able to predict EF's save order ... nor have I bothered to try, given the principles involved.

Comment: Ward, I am using EF. The order is important as in this case the first item is the main one. I see your point on orderby, but I would expect this to behave the same way if I inserted the records directly into the database through insert statements. A SQL Server table with only an identity key (and no other indexes) will automatically sort by the identity. But if the problem lies on EF I guess there's nothing that can be done from Breeze's perspective.

Comment: Actually, the query actually is returned in Id order when there is no OrderBy clause. Unfortunately for you, that is after it has inserted them into the db "backwards" from your perspective. You've chosen to let EF do the insert and let the DB generate your keys. I don't have a great answer for you at the moment. Never have.

Comment: You know you could call my bluff and see if you can make EF respect the order in which you add them to its DbContext. If you can make EF insert them in a particular order (remember that the temp keys are negative), then I'll look again to see if there is something we can do. But I don't think you can control EF's insert order at all

Comment: Just confirmed with SQL Server Profiler the insert statements are indeed sent in the wrong order. I will investigate further to see if that can be fixed.

Comment: It appears that this is indeed an EF thing based on the number of questions regarding the same problem in StackOverflow alone. I implemented your suggestion and added an Ordering column which I order by when retrieving the owners.

Comment: It's kind of bothering to me that newer transactions gets a lower id. Before EF fixes its problem, is there a way to workaround in Breeze?

Comment: You could reverse the order before you send them. That might work. Try the datasource adapter's `changeRequestInterceptor`.  Or you could just ignore it because, honestly, id and save order are not supposed to matter at the business level. Presentation in the UI is a different matter and that can be governed by many different things  (time, alpha, etc.)