# Hibernate does wrong insertion order for child entities with composite keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a table that relies on insertion order (bad legacy design that I cannot change) and is having transient entities being inserted in the wrong order. The table in question is called 'Mean' which is a child entity of 'Belief'. When `session.save(belief);` is called, the action is cascaded to the child mean entities which is stored as a list in the belief class. the Mean entities are stored in the appropriate order in the belief.getMeans() List, but once persisted to the database, they are inserted in order of their composite key. so for example, if there are 3 Mean entities to be inserted with the following order and composite keys:

```
[1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 2]
```

They will be inserted ordered by the composite keys like so:

```
[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]
```

Any idea as to what might be causing this? I thought Hibernate was supposed to insert based on the order they appear in the List?
I even tried running session.save() on each Mean entity individually to see if that would make a difference, but it didn't.

I appreciate your help!

EDIT: So what I ended up doing was adding a new column to the Mean table called col_index which holds the column index of the Mean in the resulting matrix. I used javax.persistence.OrderBy annotation with the new col_index column so the List of Mean entities comes back in the appropriate order. Although, this still does not fix the insertion order problem, and I would still like to have an answer for that. However for now, this solution will have to suffice.

Comment: May I know how insertion order is reliable/ has effects on a table?

Comment: The order the mean entities are inserted in is also what determines the column index for the mean in the resulting matrix. So if two entities are switched on insertion (like in the example), then those columns switch.

Comment: Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921442/row-insertion-order-entity-framework) It might be of help - not the answer, the question specifies he used a save after every insertion rather than a transaction to preserve the order

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [@OrderColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) and not [@OrderBy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html).

The `@OrderBy` annotation is used when fetching Collection elements but the order is not maintained by Hibernate.

The [`@OrderColumn` allows Hibernate](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-optimize-hibernate-elementcollection-statements/) to persist the element Collection index into the designated order column, which is then used when fetching the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate annotation, you can use the @OrderBy("") annotation to specify the order of your child entities. Please refer [this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html)

May be you should be using a separate property to customize the sort and use the property in the @OrderBy.

Comment: So that explains why it is ordering on the primary key because it is the default. But how could It get it to order by the original order? I do not see that option in those docs.